# How to fix : "Run-time error 1005 : Method SaveAs of object '_Workbook' failed"

Tags: excel, vba

I tried using this code on Mac, in which I try to save each tab from a single book individually as a new file. It not work.

```
Sub SplitEachWorkSheet()

Dim FPath As String
FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
   ws.Copy
   Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FPath & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsx"
   Application.ActiveWorkbook.Closes False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: idk, this was pc code I took

Comment: I thought `:` was the path separator in Mac.

Comment: wait then how do i fix this

Comment: oh nvm me very dumb

Comment: wait still not work

Comment: `Close` not `Closes`.   Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.pathseparator